# Slider .ui-widget-header not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

At http://eloboosterz.com/buywins/buywins.html the slider works as he is supposed to. I copied the 
code at
http://eloboosterz.com/v2/buywins.php
 but i am wondering why the slider value is changing but not the grafic.
Heres the code:

```
                  <div id="slide_div"class="slider">


    <div id="slider-result">0</div>   
  <!--<input type="hidden" id="hidden"/>-->

       <script> 

        $( ".slider" ).slider({
      animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 3,
            min: 3,
            max: 30,
    step: 1,

    //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-result" ).html(  ui.value );
                 writePrice();
            },

    //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
           change: function(event, ui) { 



            }

    });


    </script> 
    <div id="price"> PRICE</div>
```

```
  </div><!--end class slider-->
```

Ok i fixed it. In order to let the slider work i needed to delete writePrice() in my Js since i didnt define it yet.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the js console, you'll notice a couple of errors, fix them, right now it doesn't work because the code depends on the select with name "current_Tier"

Comment: yeah i changed it. its still about the fact that if u try to move the slider it somehow works because he is changing the value - but no grafical effect.

Comment: I compared the slider on the site which works with the nonworking site with the help of firebug and found out that its .ui-slider-handle which makes the grafic effect! unfortunately .ui-slider-handle doesnt change when i move the slider( on the nonworking site)